# Как обращаться к файлам Drawable по-порядку?

Tags: java, android

В папке Drawable находятся картинки с названиями im1.jpg, im2.jpg,...im30.jpg (30 штук)
Есть объект User, содержащий int-поле для хранения ID картинки и String-поле для имени
Мне нужно в цикле создать массив из 30 объектов User.

```
private List<User> users= new ArrayList<>(30);
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
            users.set(i, new User("name"+i, R.drawable.im1));
        }
```

Подскажите, как написать второй аргумент для User, чтобы каждый новый объект получал следующую картинку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что тут можно сделать по другому, более красиво и правильно, но если отвечать на ваш вопрос, то можно воспользоваться методом [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
private List<User> users= new ArrayList<>(30);
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
        int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/im"+i+1, null, getPackageName())
        users.set(i, new User("name"+i, imgId));
}
```

Comment: @ ermak0ff, подскажите как сделать правильно

Comment: @gibsonff тут зависит от конечной задачи, то что видно сейчас это больше похоже на какую то заглушку со статическими данными для наполнения и тестирования.

Comment: Я бы на всякий случай обернул бы этот код в **try-catch**, чтоб перехватить `NotFoundException`

Comment: @Circassian getIdentifier() вроде как вернет 0, если ресурс по названию не будет найдет, оставим это на откуп ТС, который по всей видимости далее где то будет эти картинки отображать.